# wordpress custom query with meta data

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to get the latest post with a meta value of headline, but it gives me the latest post made instead. Here is my query, what am i doing wrong?

```
$querydetails = "
        SELECT $wpdb->posts.* 
        FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta
        WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id  
        AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = 'headline'
        AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'custom_select'
        AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
        AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post'
        ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ";

    $headline = $wpdb->get_results($querydetails, OBJECT);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it in [wp_query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query),
The code below should do it.

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_key' => 'custom_select',
    'meta_value' => 'headline',
    'posts_per_page' => '1', //limit
    'paged' => get_query_var( 'page' ),
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'orderby' => 'date'
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
?>
```

This way you can use the default wordpress tags  like `the_content()` in a [loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)

Comment: Thanks! that worked! What is wrong with the way i was doing it?

Comment: I'm not sure, but you can check the query WP_query made with `echo $query->request`